# Graph of the following code

Tags: plotting

How to find out the exact coordinates of the following graph, as I am looking for a sine or cosine wave inside of the straight line. Although it is shown as a straight line, inside of that line there is some wave-like structure. I need to go smallest coordinate. Is there any way to find the exact curve graph inside of the straight line?

```
Q2 = Plot[Abs[T2[flux]]^2, {flux, -3, 3}, Axes -> False,Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0.41343977360505146`, 0.41343977360505146`}},
  PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2], Red}, GridLines -> {{0, 1, 2}, {}},
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dashed],
  FrameLabel -> {"Mag. Flux", "T(E)"}, BaseStyle -> {"Helvetica", 10}]
```

[image]

like this figure,
[image]

Comment: T2[flux] is long code, so I skipped that part from here. Just need to know how to find out the curve of the straight line.

Comment: Try something like `Cases[Q2, Line[arg__]:>arg,Infinity]` One of the results  should be the coordinates of your curve.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I did it but I got {{{-3., 0.411161}, {-2.94111, 0.411161}, {-2.88223, 0.411161} and more, y argument is almost equal. But I am looking for code how to get second one from the 1st figure. As the second one is other program code.

Comment: Try `range={FindMinimum[T2[flux],flux][[1]],FindMaximum[T2[flux],flux][[1]]}; Plot[T2[flux],...PlotRange->{{-3,3},range},...]` You may need to add constraints on the range of `flux` inside `FindMinimum` and `FindMaximum` Read the documentation to see how to do that. We cannot tell you much more without knowing your code for `T2` Get that range correct and then your graph should be what you are asking for.

Comment: If you set `PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0.4220,4226`}}`you will get the second figure.